# Is it a good idea to compress images on client before upload

Tags: reactjs, web, image-processing

I am trying to understand the cost of performance hit it will take and the task required at hand for entry point.

For instance, it makes sense to compress the images before uploading the source - The client.

But at the same time if run the compression algorithm. Would't it take the hit for performance?
I run React on server (NodeJS), so I have one more layer, So shall client or NodejS server ( Front-end server ) or backend server take the compression part? We store these images in s3 eventually.

Comment: It entirely depends. Are you starting out with an already compressed format like JPG or PNG? Then there's probably very little advantage to trying to squeeze out more compression from that. OTOH, if you're starting with raw BMP or TIFF images or such, you can probably compress those a lot. But, consider whether you can live with the lost quality or whether you need the highest quality possible.

Comment: Next, what are you doing with the images on the server that might be "costly"? Even a few MB more or less aren't a big deal these days. Unless a lot of visitors will *download* those few MB over and over again, which might not be optimal. But then you'd probably want your server to be in control of that, not the client.

Comment: Ideally what @deceze mentioned is right. But I would suggest ask this question yourself. If you website is image oriented? Yes then handle from your client side or use any other services. I also stuck at some time. I debug this and wrote an article about this as well. Feel free to checkout if you need to compress from npm side. Here is blog [url](https://shubhamverma.dev/) for reference

Comment: @deceze my question is that should server handle the compression if the a JPEG image is 3Mb or should a web client do it?

Comment: To give more context, I run React on server (NodeJS), so I have one more layer, So shall client or NodejS server ( Front-end server ) or backend server take the compression part? We store these images in s3 eventually

Comment: Generally, whenever you let the client do something, you cannot rely on it doing it. I.e., somebody poking around your app may bypass that compression step and upload uncompressed images anyway. What now? Is that an issue? You decide. Further, depending on what your client is exactly, running compression on it may or may not be feasible. A native app can do that relatively easily. Some browser Javascript less so. Some browser Javascript on a mobile, maybe even less so. Lastly, will your server post-process the image anyway, e.g. produce smaller thumbnails of it? Then what's the gain?

Comment: Didn't quite get the last line about the gain.  I am just interested in reducing the quality of it without resizing them. We have Q&A website which allows user to ask questions via image upload as well. We scan the image via API and provide relevant answers to their question @deceze

Comment: So you're doing OCR? I'd think you'd want the highest possible quality image then, no? If the original is already grainy and you compress it further, you might inadvertently destroy your chance of scanning it correctly.

Comment: Ye. So what if I keep a lower threshold for images from which point upwards I would compress it else I would not touch it.